# How to calculate the percentage returns in a dataframe with multiple securities?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, tapply

I have a dataframe is constructed like this:

```
    SecTicker Price
[1]    X     10
[2]    X     12
[3]    X     11
[4]    Y     5
[5]    Y     8
[6]    Y     4 
    etc...
```

I would like to insert a column that has the returns of the security for each day, so kinda looks like this

```
    SecTicker Price     ret
[1] X         10         NA
[2] X         12         .2 
[3] X         11         -.0833 
[4] Y         5          NA 
[5] Y         8          .6  
[6] Y         4          -.5
```

So essentially just (Price(current) / Price (Time -1) )  -1 for each column, with the first row for each ticker as an NA

Looking a little bit into tapply(), I am still unsure how to calculate the difference since I am referring to the same column. Is there any advice on how to go about this? I would appreciate the help

Comment: `df$ret <- unlist(tapply(df$Price, df$SecTicker, function(x) c(NA, x[-1]/x[-length(x)] - 1)))` if you want to use `tapply`.

Comment: :) ! thanks! That 'x[-1]/x[-length(x)]' component is genius

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to `data.frame`, take the `lag` of 'Price`and divide it by 'Price' after grouping by 'SecTicker` (using `data.table`).

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(m1)[, Price := as.numeric(Price)
    ][, ret := round((Price/shift(Price))-1, 2), by = SecTicker][]
#   SecTicker Price   ret
#1:         X    10    NA
#2:         X    12  0.20
#3:         X    11 -0.08
#4:         Y     5    NA
#5:         Y     8  0.60
#6:         Y     4 -0.50
```

Based on the example showed, it appears the dataset is `matrix`, but `matrix` can hold only a single `class`.  As there is a `character` class column, after converting to `data.table`, change the class of 'Price' to `numeric` before creating the 'ret'

If it is a `data.frame`, then

```
setDT(df1)[, ret := round((Price/shift(Price))-1, 2), by = SecTicker][]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a base `R` solution, I would begin with the `by` function

```
newdata <- by(origdata[["Price"]], INDICES = origdata["SecTicker"], 
              FUN = function(x) data.frame(Price = x, ret = x/c(NA, x[-(length(x))]) - 1))
```

This gives you a list with the `SecTicker` as the name and in each list element is a data frame containing the `Price` and `ret` values.  You can get the `data.frame` format back using.

```
finaldata <- do.call(function(...) rbind(..., make.row.names = FALSE), newdata)
finaldata[["SecTicker"]] <- rep(names(newdata), 
                                vapply(newdata, nrow, numeric(1)))
```